# unfold 360 video with opencv vs pixpro 360 VR suite

Tags: windows, opencv, video-processing, 360-degrees

I am trying to implement the unfolding of a 360 video with opencv (c++, Windows).  I used cv::remap. It takes several minutes for a video of, say, 1 min.

I compared my results with the output of the Kodak PixPro 360 VR Suite software. When exporting a panoramic video with the software, it takes some time and the quality of my unfolding is equivalent : good.

However, the software also proposes to load a 360 video and **directly play it unfolded** : meaning that the unfolding process is really fast (no lag), and I can see that the quality was also way better than mine or the soft exported one.

How is that possible ? **How can we unfold a 360 video at play speed** ? Is it something they can "hide" in the file metadata ??

Note : Pixpro also provides other transforms, all playing along at play speed with no lag.

Thanks !!